# How can Use IADF-IAVFF 1.0 Fiji-Plugins Java/python

Tags: java, python-3.x, fiji

A new Fiji-plugin for visualizing intra-annual density fluctuations and
analyzing intra-annual theoretical volumetric flow rate fluctuations
along wood cross-sections
hello to you all, I try to use this new fiji-plugin to perform the analysis of my tracheids. The precursor steps to image processing (positioning, treshold ect.) Are complete. Once the plugin activated an error message appears in the console of java

console:

> Failed to install  java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: cp0.
>   [ERROR] null

followed by

> [ERROR] null
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File “IADF-IAVFF_1.0.py”, line 51, in 
>   NameError: name ‘ResultsTable’ is not defined

I joined  the python script
Thank you so much for your help

```
import sys
import math
from ij import IJ
from ij.gui import GenericDialog

#Dialog for chosing the analysing mode
def getMode(): 
  gd = GenericDialog("Intra annual analyses")
  gd.addMessage("Please choose the analysing mode (picture requirements):\n \n[1] IADF-analysis (binary picture: white cell lumen, black cell walls)\n \n[2] IAVFF-analysis (binary picture: white cell walls, black cell lumen)")
  types = ["IADF", "IAVFF"]
  gd.addChoice("        analysing mode:", types, types[0])
  gd.showDialog()
  if gd.wasCanceled():
    sys.exit();
  IA = gd.getNextChoice()
  return IA

#Dialog for entering Hagen-Poiseuille equation parameter
def getParameter():
  gd = GenericDialog("Hagen-Poiseuille equation parameter")
  gd.addNumericField("dynamic fluid viscosity eta [mPa*s]", 1, 0)   
  gd.addNumericField("length of pipe L [m]", 1, 0)  
  gd.addNumericField("pressure difference delta p [MPa]", 1, 0)   
  gd.showDialog()
  if gd.wasCanceled():
    sys.exit();
  nu = gd.getNextNumber() 
  L = gd.getNextNumber() 
  p = gd.getNextNumber() 
  return nu, L, p

#Obtain Image, Image Processor, height and width
imp = IJ.getImage()
ip = imp.getProcessor().convertToFloat()
x = imp.getWidth()
y = imp.getHeight()
j = 1
i = 1
row = 0
grey = 1.0
sapf_list = []
sapf_pix_list = []

#Chosing analysing mode
mode = getMode()
IA = mode

# IADF-analysis
IJ.run("Set Measurements...", "area centroid perimeter shape feret's area_fraction redirect=None decimal=0")
if IA == "IADF":  
  table = ResultsTable()
  for j in range(x):
    su = 0
    sup = 0
    for i in range(y):  
      if ip.getPixelValue(j,i) > 0:
        su = su + 1
      else:
        su = su + 0  
    sup = round(float(su) / y * 100, 2)
    table.incrementCounter()
    table.addValue("sum of black pixel", su)
    table.addValue("percent of black pixel", sup)

  table.show("Results")

# IAVFF-analysis
else: 
  parameter = getParameter()
  nu, L, p = parameter
  IJ.run("Set Measurements...", "area centroid perimeter shape feret's area_fraction redirect=None decimal=3")
  IJ.run("Set Scale...")
  imp32 = imp.duplicate()
  IJ.run("Analyze Particles...")
  rt = ResultsTable.getResultsTable()
  IJ.run(imp32, "32-bit", "")


  for roi in RoiManager.getInstance().getRoisAsArray():

    ip = imp.getProcessor()
    a = rt.getValue("Feret", row)
    b = rt.getValue("MinFeret", row)
    sapf = (math.pi/4) * (1/(nu*L)) * math.pow(a/1000000, 3) * math.pow(b/1000000, 3) / (math.pow(a/1000000, 2) + math.pow(a/1000000, 2))*(p/1000000000)
    sapf_list.append(sapf)
    rt.setValue("ROI no.", row, row + 1)
    rt.setValue("Q", row, sapf)
    ip.setRoi(roi)
    stats = ImageStatistics.getStatistics(ip, Measurements.AREA, None)
    rt.setValue("Pixel count", row, stats.pixelCount)
    rt.setValue("Q per Pixel", row, sapf/stats.pixelCount)
    sapf_pix_list.append(sapf/stats.pixelCount)
    row = row + 1

    ip = imp32.getProcessor()
    ip.setRoi(roi)
    stats = ip.getStatistics()
    ip.setValue(grey)
    ip.fill(roi)
    ip.resetRoi() 
    grey = grey + 1.0

  imp32.show()
  rt.show("Results") 
  table = ResultsTable()
  sapf_pix_row_list = []

  for j in range(x):
    IJ.showProgress(j, x)
    sum_sapf_pix = 0
    for i in range(y):  
       if ip.getPixelValue(j, i) != 0.0:
         pos = int(ip.getPixelValue(j, i))-1
         sum_sapf_pix = sum_sapf_pix + sapf_pix_list[pos]       

    table.incrementCounter()
    table.addValue("Q pixel-row sum", sum_sapf_pix)
  IJ.showProgress(1)
  table.show("IAVFF-Results")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix UnsupportedCharsetException in Eclipse Kepler/Luna with Jython/PyDev?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30443537)

Answer (score 0):

Jython-shaded-2.7.x.jar is not compatible with Fiji!
Change it to Jython-shapde-2.5.3.jar!

1) Download Jython-shapde-2.5.3.jar as below
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scijava/jython-shaded/2.5.3

2) Remove Jython-shaded-2.7.0.jar(for example) from Fuji.App/jars folder and put Jython-shapde-2.5.3.jar instead!

3) Restart Fiji