# Jython CP720 is not supported in this JVM so it can't be used in python.console.encoding

Tags: java, python, windows, cmd, jython

I want to start using Jython ,I downloaded and installed jython 2.5.2 , i have JDK 1.8 installed and python 3.7 already.
After installing jython and following this [Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jython/jython_installation.htm) and running this command:

```
C:\jython2.5.2\bin>jython
```

I get this output in the CMD , windows 7 32 bit machine

> C:\jython2.5.2\bin>jython
>   Jython 2.5.2 (Release_2_5_2:7206, Mar 2 2011, 23:12:06)
>   [Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.8.0_161
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>   cp720 is not a supported encoding on this JVM, so it can't be used in python.con
>   sole.encoding.

What to do?
**Edit** It was Windows CMD encoding problem, It doesn't accept `cp720` so How can I force the CMD to use `utf-8` instead for running jython?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443537/how-do-i-fix-unsupportedcharsetexception-in-eclipse-kepler-luna-with-jython-pyde suggest passing `-Dpython.console.encoding=UTF-8` as a commandline argument (I just don't know if that works for the jython executable).

Comment: It worked Thanks :) !!, Idk how to mark ur answer as correct or what to do next

Comment: I'll post a real answer based on my comment in a few minutes, you can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [How do I fix UnsupportedCharsetException in Eclipse Kepler/Luna with Jython/PyDev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443537/how-do-i-fix-unsupportedcharsetexception-in-eclipse-kepler-luna-with-jython-pyde) you'll need to pass `-Dpython.console.encoding=UTF-8` (or a different character set) on the command line:

```
jython -Dpython.console.encoding=UTF-8
```