# Pass Java string argument to Jython interpreter

Tags: java, python, printing, jython

I need to pass a java string value (a path to a pdf file) to a function in the Jython interpreter, that is `os.startfile(filename, "print")` (where filename is the string). So i tried to write it like this:

```
 import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

 PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
 interpreter.set("filename", fileDaStampare);
 interpreter.exec("import os");
 interpreter.exec("os.startfile(filename, \"print\")");
```

but it returns me this error when I execute tha java program:

> console: Failed to install '':
>   java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: cp0. Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "", line 1, in 
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'startfile'

What can I do to execute this little piece of code in the Python interpreter?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443537/how-do-i-fix-unsupportedcharsetexception-in-eclipse-kepler-luna-with-jython-pyde)?

Comment: @user7217806: I tried and the first error just disappeared, but the second one persists: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'startfile'

Comment: `os.startfile` does not exist in Jython. See this old but unresolved issue: https://bugs.jython.org/issue1100.

Comment: I tried the solution described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195594/python-silent-print-pdf-to-specific-printer/51325336 but even win32api and win32print return this:   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'win32api' is not defined