# Is there a way to run Python code in Pydev?

Tags: python, eclipse, jython, pydev

I'm new to Jython and PyDev. I need to run my Python code in Eclipse. 
The Python code works in Spyder/Jupyter Notebooks. When I run the programm as Jython Run/Python Run, an error pops up.
How can I solve this problem?

```html
console: Failed to install '': java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: cp0.
C:\Users\Hai Mi\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:140: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hai Mi\workspace\Camunda\learning_classify.py", line 7, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "C:\Users\Hai Mi\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "C:\Users\Hai Mi\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\nltk\collocations.py", line 40, in <module>
    from nltk.metrics import ContingencyMeasures, BigramAssocMeasures, TrigramAssocMeasures, QuadgramAssocMeasures
  File "C:\Users\Hai Mi\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\nltk\metrics\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from nltk.metrics.scores import (
  File "C:\Users\Hai Mi\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\nltk\metrics\scores.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scipy.stats.stats import betai
  File "C:\Users\Hai Mi\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\nltk\metrics\scores.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scipy.stats.stats import betai
  File "C:\Users\Hai Mi\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
  File "C:\Users\Hai Mi\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\Hai Mi\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\Hai Mi\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\Hai Mi\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Users\Hai Mi\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 166
SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function 'decorator' because it contains free variables
```

Comment: Did you try the help URL included in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a similar issue was discussed here
[How do I fix UnsupportedCharsetException in Eclipse Kepler/Luna with Jython/PyDev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443537/how-do-i-fix-unsupportedcharsetexception-in-eclipse-kepler-luna-with-jython-pyde)
and adding

> -Dpython.console.encoding=UTF-8

to the Run Configurations -> VM arguments could be a solution.